# How to enable or disable highlight matching tag

Tags: ace-editor

In the editor the matching opening or closing tag is being selected. Looking through the documentation I've found the method jumpToMatching(Object select) but I don't see a method to disable or enable this feature.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: Personally I like it. But I'm making a property inspector like the kitchen sink example so I'm just looking for the option to enable or disable it.

Comment: FYI for your consideration: I'm creating a read only view and it would be nice to have this option integrated into the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest hiding it with CSS. The only drawback is that this will globally disable all bracket highlighting, not just for HTML tags.

```
.ace_editor .ace_marker-layer .ace_bracket { display: none }
```

See a working demo below:

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/dreamweaver");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
```

```css
#editor {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#editor .ace_marker-layer .ace_bracket { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/ace@1.2.3(min/ace.js+min/mode-html.js+min/theme-dreamweaver.js)" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="editor">&lt;html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
 &lt;head>
  &lt;style type="text/css" media="screen">
   html, body {
    height: 100%;
   }
  &lt;/style>
 &lt;/head>
&lt;/html></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting of matching tags and brackets is always enabled it should be possible to add option to not highlight here https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/editor.js#L535.

Comment: I've made an attempt at a patch in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to manually disable it and then enable it again:

```
function toggleMatchingTagStyle() {
    if (editor.$highlightTagPending == true) {
        editor.$highlightTagPending = false;
        editor.$highlightPending = false;
    }
    else {
        session.removeMarker(session.$tagHighlight);
        session.$tagHighlight = null;
        session.removeMarker(session.$bracketHighlight);
        session.$bracketHighlight = null;
        editor.$highlightTagPending = true;
        editor.$highlightPending = true;
    }
}
```

And here is a rough patch that I think will work to editor.js to enable or disable this feature:

for old style getter setter functions

```
this.setHighlightMatchingTags = function(shouldHighlight) {
    this.setOption("highlightMatchingTags", shouldHighlight);
};

this.getHighlightMatchingTags = function() {
    return this.getOption("highlightMatchingTags");
};

this.setHighlightMatchingBrackets = function(shouldHighlight) {
    this.setOption("highlightMatchingBrackets", shouldHighlight);
};

this.getHighlightMatchingBrackets = function() {
    return this.getOption("highlightMatchingBrackets");
};
```

for setOption() in [editor.js#L2624](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/editor.js#L2624) add

```
highlightMatchingTags: {
    set: function(shouldHighlight) {this.$onSelectionChange();},
    initialValue: true
},
highlightMatchingBrackets: {
    set: function(shouldHighlight) {this.$onSelectionChange();},
    initialValue: true
},
```

Change this (line 505):

```
this.$highlightBrackets = function() {
```

To this:

```
this.$highlightBrackets = function() {
    if (!this.$highlightMatchingBrackets) return;
```

Change this (line 534):

```
this.$highlightTags = function() {
```

To this:

```
this.$highlightTags = function() {
    if (!this.$highlightMatchingTags) return;
```